# Backup APP registration settings in Azure

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, azure-application-settings

I have a question about an APP registration/recovery:  We have an App that uses Graph and EWS Microsoft 365 APIs.  Customers can use our tenant registration but once we have distributed the app, we are concerned about losing/damaging the AppID in the future (affecting thousands of users).

What is the process to backup the AppID and its settings, and to restore the same AppID?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore application  by using application object id using  PowerShell

```
Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication -ObjectId <objectid>
```

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/restore-azureaddeletedapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)